# Linear or Relative Layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, adt

just having a tough time forming my layout. I mocked up a Photoshop example of what I'm trying to accomplish real quick.

I have been trying to form this layout with a Relative Layout but it's not working like I thought it would, should I use a LinearLayout perhaps? Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Here's the example:]

**EDIT**

http://i58.tinypic.com/axxjdl.png

Made a few minor changes to the layout, but nested relativeLayoutss inside a linearLayout worked perfectly. Now just having trouble making those bottom 3 settings buttons center, meh oh well I'll figure it out.

Comment: Either will work.  Each has its pluses/minuses.  For true help, post what you've tried and where you're getting stuck.

Comment: you can also archived using bunch of Linear Layout...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use nested layouts, after all a layout is a `View`.

Your example looks like `LinearLayout` at root and a `RelativeLayout` for each row. If you're making several rows you should look into the details of a `ListView`.

Comment: My god, thank you SO MUCH Dan, I would vote up if I could. This is exactly the sort of answer I was looking for, and I will also look into ListView. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Sparchitect Please accept this as an answer if it solves your problem.